# Inject angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this structure in my script A:

```
module.exports = angular.module('myApp').controller(..).directive(..)
```

I want to inject additional directive so that I have something like this:

```
module.exports = angular.module('myApp').controller(..).directive(..).directive(..)
```

I want to do this from the outside of the script A.

Any ideas how this can be achieved? I am still catching up with the angular, and any help is really appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create your directive dynamically. (within different angular module) You can code in the way blow,

```
//dynamic directive    dyDir.js
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.directive(...)
};
```

your script

```
var dyDir = require('./dyDir.js');

var yourApp = angular.module('appName',[]);
yourApp.controller('testCtrl', ...)
dyDir(yourApp); //parse angular module instance as parameter
```

Although this would work, but I really don't think use `angular.module` and the `commonjs module` at the same time is a good practice, coz this would make the other developer so confused.

Hope this would solve your problem. : )

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Actually, I would like to inject my directive into the existing angular module. I am trying to reuse an existing code here.I tried what you said, but I cannot say if that works because I cannot get my script invoked.I have assets.yaml file that includes dependencies for the script with the "module.exports=.." (I would like to change), and I added a dependency on dyDir.js, but that does not seem to work.This seems to be an another problem. I am working on it, and would appreciate if you have any idea.Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved in a following way - if it can be of any help to anyone:

Assume you have an existing module myModule, and two controllers myController1 and myController2 (code for the two controllers is in files controller1.js and controller2.js). This is your code in a file myapp.js:

```
module.exports = angular.module("myModule", [])
.controller('myController1', require('./controller1.js'))
.controller('myController2', require('./controller2.js'))
```

Assume you would like to inject additional directive into your module myModule. You would reuse that module.

You would create a new file with the following content:

```
require('./myapp.js');
require('./mydirective.js'); //this is your new directive
var app = angular.module("myModule"); //get an existing module

app.directive('directiveName', function() {
    return {
        ...
    }
})
```